# sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is group writable

Tags: permissions, 22.04, sudo, filesystem, etc

I've made a mistake. List of commands that I typed:

- `sudo usermod -a -G root erp`
- `sudo chmod g+w /etc`
- `setfacl -R -m u:erp:rwx /etc`

Then `ssh.service` of the virtual machine stopped working and when I type commands with sudo in terminal, it says **sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is group writable**.

And after googling for some time, it seems what I have done is similar to `chmod -R 777 /`. I'm hoping that I don't need to reinstall the Ubuntu OS on this machine. Is what I have done actually revertible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have enabled a **recursive** ACL on the entire `/etc` directory. Run this to remove all ACLs recursively:

```
setfacl -b -R /etc
```

If you are still getting the error, post the output of `ls -alh /etc/sudo.conf`, if it has group write you can probably remove it with `chmod g-w`.

In the future, do not run commands that you don't understand. Use something like https://explainshell.com/ or read man pages.

Comment: Thank you for your response, sir. I've just tried that command. On top of that, I typed ```chmod 640 /etc/sudo.conf``` and the message ```sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is group writable``` no longer appears when i type with sudo. And there are two services that failed to start which are postgresql and ssh. Do I have to reinstall it?

Comment: Just try restarting them with `systemctl restart [name]`, if they don't start inspect the logs with `journalctl -u [name]` to figure out why they are not starting. This should be done as root.

Comment: It restarts without a problem. Thank you, good sir.